# Apollo Server, datasource-sql sub-class not being recognised as a valid DataSource type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, apollo, apollo-server

I am adding Typescript to an existing Nodejs Apollo Server project and am having some issues with the datasource-sql library.

My sql client class simplified ...

```
import { SQLDataSource } from "datasource-sql";

export default class CtlDatabase extends SQLDataSource {
  ...
}
```

And referenced in my main index.ts file which sets up the Apollo Server datasources ...

```
import CtlDatabase from './dataSources/CtlDatabase';
...
const dataSources = (): DataSources<Context['dataSources']> => {
  return {
    ctlDatabase: new CtlDatabase(config),
  }
};
```

Typescript doesn't seem to pickup the SQLDataSource inheritance at all, it even shows issues relating to passing the config in the constructor; even though that is valid syntax according to the SQLDataSource definition.

https://github.com/cvburgess/SQLDataSource/blob/master/index.js

You can see the SQLDataSource Class also extends the DataSource class.

Here are the errors -

> Type 'CtlDatabase' has no properties in common with type 'DataSource<{ ctlDatabase: CtlDatabase; pathway: PathwayEWS; atenPathway: AtenPathwayApi; }>'.

And showing it's lack of knowledge of the SQLDataSource class

> Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Error in my sql client package regarding the import definition -

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'datasource-sql'. '/home/russjb/Work/codeforaustralia/CBC-Backend/node_modules/datasource-sql/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

How do I resolve this?
Do I have to define my own Types for that package?
How can I do that?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Node 14",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/",                          
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "es2020",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }  ,
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

Any help much appreciated!
New to TypeScript so it's all a learning curve.

FWIW I am also using the apollo rest datasource with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are inherithing but the CtlDatabase constructor has no parameter.

You should receive a parameter in the CtlDatabase constructor and then call super(config)

export default class CtlDatabase extends SQLDataSource
constructor(config: any)
super(config) ;
//CODE GOES HERE

Comment: The constructor is inherited from the SQLDataSource class, I don't have one defined in my class. I do pass a config to the constructor when I create the instance.

I figured out a solution and will post it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to my problem; without any TS definitions for the `datasource-sql` module TypeScript just inherits it as any, thus it doesn't see the DataSource inheritance further up the line, it doesn't even identify the class that's being exported from the module.

To resolve I had to add my own TypeScript declaration file (`.d.ts`) for the module, guide here -
https://medium.com/@chris_72272/migrating-to-typescript-write-a-declaration-file-for-a-third-party-npm-module-b1f75808ed2

My declaration file `datasource-sql.d.ts`

```
declare module 'datasource-sql'{
  export class SQLDataSource {
    constructor(knexConfig?: any);
    initialize?(config: DataSourceConfig<TContext>): void;
    knex: any;
  }
};
```

It is not pretty and it's doing the bare minimum of what I need.
Next step would be to properly set the knex property so that my package is more aware of everything that knex can do.

Also added this to the top of my main index file -

```
/// <reference path="./dataSources/CtlDatabase/datasource-sql.d.ts"/>
```

It's not pretty at all but it has allowed me to move forwards.